# How to change some of the fields for the table in the form to display other fields in other table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, foreign-keys

I have a APPOINTMENT table which have relationship with NURSE table, MEDICALCENTRE table, and PATIENT table. In the first image attached below is my form, which displays all data from APPOINTMENT table in a data grid view. What I want to do is change the field name for patientID, mcID and nurseID to other fields in the other tables.I want patientID to display as pFirstName which exist in PATIENT table. mcID to display as mcCentre which exist in MEDICALCENTRE table. And nurseID to display as nFirstName which exist in NURSE Table. Below is my page_five form codes. What should I change in my select statement to achieved what I want to display?

//My appointment form codes

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace GRP_02_03_SACP
{
    public partial class appointment : Form
    {

        // Data Table to store employee data
        DataTable Appointment = new DataTable();

        // Keeps track of which row in Gridview
        // is selected
        DataGridViewRow currentRow = null;

        SqlDataAdapter AppointmentAdapter;

        public appointment()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void appointment_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadMedicalCentreRecords();
        }



        private void LoadMedicalCentreRecords()
        {

            //retrieve connection information info from App.config
            string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sacpConnection"].ConnectionString;
            //STEP 1: Create connection
            SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
            //STEP 2: Create command
            string strCommandText = "SELECT appointmentID, aDate, aTime, aStatus, aContact, aHeight, aWeight, patientID, mcID, nurseID  FROM APPOINTMENT";

            AppointmentAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strCommandText, myConnect);

            //command builder generates Select, update, delete and insert SQL
            // statements for MedicalCentreAdapter
            SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(AppointmentAdapter);
            // Empty Employee Table first
            Appointment.Clear();
            // Fill Employee Table with data retrieved by data adapter
            // using SELECT statement
            AppointmentAdapter.Fill(Appointment);

            // if there are records, bind to Grid view & display
            if (Appointment.Rows.Count > 0)
                grdApp.DataSource = Appointment;
        }

        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int modifiedRows = 0;
            // Get changes
            DataTable UpdatedTable = Appointment.GetChanges();
            if (UpdatedTable != null)
            {
                // there are changes
                // Write modified data to database 
                modifiedRows = AppointmentAdapter.Update(UpdatedTable);
                // accept changes
                Appointment.AcceptChanges();
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("there are no changes to update");

            if (modifiedRows > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There are " + modifiedRows + " records updated");
                LoadMedicalCentreRecords();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

APPOINTMENT FORM
[image: AppointmentForm]
APPOINTMENT TABLE
[image: AppointmentTable]
NURSE TABLE
[image: NurseTable]
MEDICALCENTRE TABLE
[image: MedicalCentreTable]
PATIENT TABLE
[image: PatientTable]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your select statement you need to join your additional tables. and replace ID with fields from those tables.

it will be something like this

```sql
SELECT appointmentID
   ,aDate
   ,aTime
   ,aStatus
   ,aContact
   ,aHeight
   ,aWeight
   ,p.pFirstName
   ,m.mcCentre
   ,n.nFirstName       
FROM APPOINTMENT AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN Nurse AS n 
ON a.nurseID = n.NurseID
Left outer join Patient as p
on a.patientid = p.patientId
left outer join medicalcentre as m
on a.mcID = m.mcid
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I can't use the update function to change the value on  all my fields values. This error (Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against multiple base tables.)  @SaUce

Comment: I created a new thread for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21201170/i-changed-some-of-my-fields-to-display-as-other-fields-in-other-table-and-now-i @SaUce