# I changed some of my fields to display as other fields in other table, and now i can't update the values

Tags: c#, sql, forms, join

Previously it worked when I display fields only on one table but now When I change the value in any fields, and clicked the update button, it gives me (Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against multiple base tables.)  Help.

appointment form
[image: appointmentform]

Error updateing
[image: errorupdating]

Appointment table
[image: Appointment table]

nurse table
[image: nurse table]

medicalcentre table
[image: medicalcentretable]

patient table
[image: patient table]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace GRP_02_03_SACP
{
    public partial class appointment : Form
    {

        // Data Table to store employee data
        DataTable Appointment = new DataTable();

        // Keeps track of which row in Gridview
        // is selected
        DataGridViewRow currentRow = null;

        SqlDataAdapter AppointmentAdapter;

        public appointment()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void appointment_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadMedicalCentreRecords();
        }



        private void LoadMedicalCentreRecords()
        {

            //retrieve connection information info from App.config
            string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sacpConnection"].ConnectionString;
            //STEP 1: Create connection
            SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
            //STEP 2: Create command
            string strCommandText = "SELECT appointmentID, aDate, aTime, aStatus, aContact, aHeight, aWeight, p.pFirstName , m.mcCentre , n.nFirstName FROM APPOINTMENT AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN Nurse AS n ON a.nurseID = n.NurseID Left outer join Patient as p on a.patientid = p.patientId left outer join medicalcentre as m on a.mcID = m.mcid";

            AppointmentAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strCommandText, myConnect);

            //command builder generates Select, update, delete and insert SQL
            // statements for MedicalCentreAdapter
            SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(AppointmentAdapter);
            // Empty Employee Table first
            Appointment.Clear();
            // Fill Employee Table with data retrieved by data adapter
            // using SELECT statement
            AppointmentAdapter.Fill(Appointment);

            // if there are records, bind to Grid view & display
            if (Appointment.Rows.Count > 0)
                grdApp.DataSource = Appointment;
        }

        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int modifiedRows = 0;
            // Get changes
            DataTable UpdatedTable = Appointment.GetChanges();
            if (UpdatedTable != null)
            {
                // there are changes
                // Write modified data to database 
                modifiedRows = AppointmentAdapter.Update(UpdatedTable);
                // accept changes
                Appointment.AcceptChanges();
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("there are no changes to update");

            if (modifiedRows > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There are " + modifiedRows + " records updated");
                LoadMedicalCentreRecords();
            }
        }

        private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) // this displays the dialog box and performs actions dependant on which option chosen.
            {
                printDocument1.Print();
            }
        }

        private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            int columnPosition = 0;
            int rowPosition = 25;

            // run function to draw headers
            DrawHeader(new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Bold), e.Graphics, ref columnPosition, ref rowPosition); // runs the DrawHeader function

            rowPosition += 35; // sets the distance below the header text and the next black line (ruler)

            // run function to draw each row
            DrawGridBody(e.Graphics, ref columnPosition, ref rowPosition);
        }

        // DrawHeader will draw the column title, move over, draw the next column title, move over, and continue.
        private int DrawHeader(Font boldFont, Graphics g, ref int columnPosition, ref int rowPosition)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn dc in grdApp.Columns)
            {

                //MessageBox.Show("dc = " + dc);

                g.DrawString(dc.HeaderText, boldFont, Brushes.Black, (float)columnPosition, (float)rowPosition);
                columnPosition += dc.Width + 5; // adds to colPos. value the width value of the column + 5. 
            }

            return columnPosition;
        }

        /* DrawGridBody will loop though each row and draw it on the screen. It starts by drawing a solid line on the screen, 
         * then it moves down a row and draws the data from the first grid column, then it moves over, then draws the data from the next column,
         * moves over, draws the data from the next column, and continus this pattern. When the entire row is drawn it starts over and draws
         * a solid line then the row data, then the next solid line and then row data, etc.
        */
        private void DrawGridBody(Graphics g, ref int columnPosition, ref int rowPosition)
        {
            // loop through each row and draw the data to the graphics surface.
            foreach (DataRow dr in ((DataTable)grdApp.DataSource).Rows)
            {
                columnPosition = 0;

                // draw a line to separate the rows 
                g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, new Point(0, rowPosition), new Point(this.Width, rowPosition));

                // loop through each column in the row, and draw the individual data item
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn dc in grdApp.Columns)
                {
                    // draw string in the column
                    string text = dr[dc.DataPropertyName].ToString();
                    g.DrawString(text, this.Font, Brushes.Black, (float)columnPosition, (float)rowPosition + 10f); // the last number (10f) sets the space between the black line (ruler) and the text below it.

                    // go to the next column position
                    columnPosition += dc.Width + 5;
                }

                // go to the next row position
                rowPosition = rowPosition + 60; // this sets the space between the row text and the black line below it (ruler).
            }
        }

        private void btnPrintPreview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // PrintPreviewDialog printPreviewDialog1 = new PrintPreviewDialog(); // instantiate new print preview dialog
                printPreviewDialog1.Document = this.printDocument1;
                if (printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) // Show the print preview dialog, uses printPage event to draw preview screen
                {
                    printDocument1.Print();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(exp.Message.ToString());
            }
        }




    }
}
```

Comment: update with join is impossible in your case

Comment: Also you could just edit your other recent post, you don't need to keep submitting new questions.

Comment: ok Noted, will do that in future. so I cannot use update function, if I want to display other fields in my table? @kumarch1

Comment: You have to execute / fire an update statement for every sql table sepatately

Comment: What do you mean, cause i don't have update statements codes in my update button. @sqlab